# find given date is business date or holiday in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I have table having customer appointment date and id. Now i want to find out appointment date is business date or holiday like saturday and sunday .

I want to find out how many customers visits on business day and holiday using  postgresql.

Table name is `customers_details` having two columns `id integer, appoinment_date date`.

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: Public holidays also

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions with a conditional expression to define the groups:

```
select
    (extract(dow from appoinment_date) in (0, 6)) is_holiday,
    count(*) no_visits
from customers_details 
group by 1
```

In the resultset, `is_holiday` is a boolean flag that indicates whether the appointment happened on a holiday (true) or on a working day (false).

Comment: while giving  next appointment date if it is holiday then how it will take next business or working day using PostgreSQL query

Comment: @RanjitChavan: that is a different question. The above answers the question that you originally asked: does the query work for you?

Comment: Perfect, except that public holidays are not catered for.